# Can Geneos Rules maintain and pass state?

Tags: geneos, itrs

In simple words within ITRS can a Rule either declare or modify a variable set at the sampler or probe level so that another Rule can get the latest value of that variable?

Alternatively is there a way to keep state within GTRS? So if a rule called Rule 1 runs, it queries the state and optionally modifies that shared state so that when it runs the next time it sees the modified state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do time series analysis on rule sets however that is not very straight forward or convenient. We ended up saving state in a SQL Server and reading that from ITRS using its Sql Server Connector.